# Selenium will not click on element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a specific statistic from a website, but I need to click on screen (as shown below) for it to be retrievable. I've tried several different methods to try and get the "click" action to work, but nothing for now. I keep getting something along the lines of

```
elements = driver.find_elements("class name", "text-center")

try:
    third_element = elements[108]
    print(third_element.text)
except IndexError:
    print("error")

This is the HTML of the "button":
<label class="btn btn-outline-dark nhl-label" for="zonetime-es">
```

This is the HTML of the stat I want (which I was only able to pull after clicking, otherwise gives me the stat at All Situations):

40.5%

Tried going right to coordinates, tells me out of range.

Tried using Selenium IDE to track what happens if I do it manually, still the same error message, but different coordinates.

Tried waiting for page to load.

Tried clicking on other "link" type buttons, which worked. Might be an issue with the HTML?

Comment: Why can't you ensure uniqueness when you write xpath or something else?

Comment: the element needs to be "clickable" to click on it.  To target the label you could use XPATH of //label[@for='zonetime-es'].   You should include the code you've tried and any exceptions you receive.

Comment: what site? It's very possible you don't need to use selenium